# Edit an existing data in plist

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

How can i override an existing data in a plist after checking if the data is already present or not, through coding

In Detail:

I am saving username and password in my plist file located in document directory. Now if user selects an change password option, the plist should check if his username exists or not. if it exists then the new password that he is entering should override the existing password in the plist.

can anyone help me with some piece of sample code

Comment: In detail: I am saving username and password in my plist file. Now if user selects an change password option, the plist should check if his username exists or not. if it exists then the new password that he is entering should override the existing password in the plist.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the plist stored in the application bundle.
If you need to edit the user data stored in the plist, then you need to create the plist on the document directory.

Another option is [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If there is huge data then I'll suggest `sqlite3` database, else you can use `plist` or `NSUserDefaults`.

You can alter the value of your plist like:

```
NSString *path = //your plist path in document directory;
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *userExist = [plistDict objectForKey:@"UserName"]; //test the user exist
if([userExist isEqualToString:@"Midhun"])                   //checking user exist or not
{
  NSString *userPwd = @"Midhun";
  [tempDict setObject:userPwd forKey:@"PassWord"]; //Password is your key
  [tempDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html) for more.
Here is a plist [tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/) for you.

Comment: I have my plist file in document directory only. I want to know how to override my existing data present of plist file that is presented in document directory

Comment: I need an sample code for: eg i have 10 entries. now i need to search my 4th entry and override my 4th entry in plist with the new data that i am entering now.

Comment: What is the key and type of that 4th entry ? 10 entries are placed asarray or string ?

Comment: in this method we should be knowing the data that is already presented in the plist. but i need a code to check if the data that i am entering now is already present in my plist file or not. if it is presented then i should override that particular value. I will be entering some 15 values in my plist. so, i should go on to the above procedure to each and every value that i am entering

Comment: @Vamsi: edited my code, for checking the user provide the key corresponding to your disctionary, if found replace the password

Comment: replace your keys with `UserName` and `PassWord`, unless it won't work

Comment: I have replaced and i ran the code. it is not overriding the plist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a data in plist if it is in your bundle directory.
Files that are present inside the bundle have "read only" permission.
While if your plist reside inside the document directory then you can edit it by using following steps.
(1)Get the data from plist.
(2)Update it.
(3)Write back the updated data to plist.

```
NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"];

if(path)

 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Update the respective dictionary dict here.

//write back to plist.

[dict writeTofile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I am creating my plist file on run time and is saving in documents folder. so, now i want to override the existing data that is present in my plist file located in documents folder

Comment: We can not write to the resource folder